# Could not install pyzmq using apt,pip,pip3,easy_install etc any command

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, pyzmq, termux

I tried everything but `pyzmq` package is not installing.

It stops while trying wheel. I even reinstalled wheel but no result.

I have already installed all basic prereq stuff. I even installed clang and go-lang but nothing works it even shows same error while installing Jupiter notebook too.

[image]

[image]

Comment: it stops while building wheel

Comment: crypt.h is part of the libc. maybe you should install "libc-dev" even if it might be part of clang package...

Comment: it turns out the package that actually contains `crypt.h` is `libcrypt-dev`. So to get rid of the error message just run `apt install libcrypt-dev` and then rerun your install

Comment: What version???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install the dev version of the libcrypt package in Termux:

```
apt install libcrypt-dev
```

This version of the package includes the required `crypt.h` header file.

## Trying it out

I dug out an old alarm clock/Android tablet I had lying around in order to test this out. I followed the instructions I found in [this blog post](http://www.leouieda.com/blog/scipy-on-android.html) to install Jupyter. After a bunch of system updates, a bricking:

[image]

and an unbricking, I ended up getting the same error that you did, and I solved it by installing the `libcrypt-dev` package. All of the Python packages were very slow to build in Termux on the tablet, but I did get Jupyter notebook to work:

[image]

So it does indeed appear that installing `libcrypt-dev` fixes the problem.

Comment: @farmanchauhan I'm actually trying it out myself right now. My tablet's ancient and uncared for tho, so I gotta wait around for a few system upgrades to download/install first. I'll let you know how it goes

Answer (score 3):

Installing `libzmq` in Termux resolved this for me:

```
pkg install libzmq
```

Comment: Thanks. Installing `libzmq` explicitly worked and I stopped getting error for python wheel build and was able to install jupyter.