# How do I install Jupyter notebook on an Android device?

Tags: android, python, jupyter, termux

Is there a way to install a functional instance of Jupyter notebook on an Android device? Specifically, I want to use Jupyter to run a Python notebook.

Comment: `Pydroid 3` app has a quick link for installing Jupyter.  I haven't tried it yet, but reviews indicate that it works.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I found some information on the web (like in [this blog post](http://www.leouieda.com/blog/scipy-on-android.html)) while I was coming up with the answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49805480/425458), but it was all at least somewhat wrong and/or out of date. Here's a complete set of working instructions:

1. Install the [Termux app](https://termux.com/).
2. Open Termux, then enter/run the following commands in the prompt:

   ```
   $ apt install clang python fftw libzmq freetype libpng pkg-config libcrypt
   $ LDFLAGS="-lm -lcompiler_rt" pip install jupyter
   ```
3. Optionally, you can install some other useful packages that mesh well with Jupyter:

   ```
   $ LDFLAGS="-lm -lcompiler_rt" pip install numpy matplotlib
   ```
4. Finally, test the notebook out by running:

   ```
   $ jupyter notebook
   ```

When you run `jupyter notebook`, a notebook server starts up and dumps some information to stdout. When you see the line:

```
Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
to login with a token:
```

copy the following URL, paste it into the browser on your device, and then hit go. You should end up with something that looks like this:

[image]

I tested these instructions out a Nexus 7 2013 (wifi) running stock Android 6.0.1 (Marshmallow).

#### Update: `<foo>-dev` packages dropped in Termux

As @OmPS pointed out in the comments, Termux dropped all of it's `<foo>-dev` packages. I've updated step 2. above to match, but I haven't tested it out since I no longer have access to my android device. If someone could please test the current version of the instructions above and then post their experience in the comments, that would be very helpful.

Comment: `apt` command did not work, but the when I replaced that command with the `pkg`  command , it did work. When you first invoke the termux and terminal, it will refer to the `pkg` command.

Comment: However I could not install scipy like I could with the other answer: `Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the                                                   numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting                                              the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.                  self.calc_info()                                        NOT AVAILABLE`

Comment: Termux never fails to amaze me!

Comment: @bgoodr same as you here. In addition, `pythin-dev`, `libzmq-dev`, `freetype-dev`, `libpng-dev` , `libcrypt-dev` all gave "Package has no installation candidate" and then in `LDFLAGS="-lm -lcompiler_rt" pip install jupyter` got "No command 'pip' found"

Comment: FYI, I also needed to install `cython` in order to get `matplotlib` running, but otherwise it worked perfectly.  I copied your method to do it: `LDFLAGS="-lm -lcompiler_rt" pip install cython`

Comment: https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/No_more_-dev_packages

no more dev packages are required with termux now.

Comment: installing jupyter lab with just `pip install jupyter-lab` worked for me after this

Comment: As far as I uderstand (not much, really) some packages need a special installation in termux, using its-pointless repo. So you first want to configure it (https://github.com/its-pointless/its-pointless.github.io) and then install scipy not ftom Python, but from the termux prompt : pkg install scipy

Comment: Even so, I had to install manually some packages that still complained (pyzlib and ccfi, I think ?) by using a plain pip install ccfi (without the LMFLAGS, and I do not have a clue why it worked...)

Comment: To achieve the whole build of jupyter in Termux I  also had to install the following packages : `rust` and `binutils`  (`apt install rust binutils`). Also, I had to use the Termux version provided by F-droid.

Answer (score 59):

Download [the app pydroid3](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.iiec.pydroid3). Open the app. On the top there is a 3-line button - click on it. There is a *PIP* option - click on it. In PIP, click on *install* and type `jupyter`. Once it gets downloaded, there is *terminal* option above pip, click on *terminal* and type `jupyter notebook`. Your work is done.

#### Edit

I got a [video explaining the download of jupyter using pydroid3](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=ORbJ21x3ulo).

Comment: I am getting error can u please help. error: https://ibb.co/bzDggB5

Answer (score 7):

I have tried the above instructions and everything works down to the tee except when the following command is run:

```
$ LDFLAGS="-lm -lcompiler_rt" pip install numpy matplotlib
```

This ends in an error that says that matplotlib could not be installed and the output advises you to install some dependencies.

My own output looks something like this:

[Screenshot of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leClN.jpg)

I googled and found that just installing a simple package through following command fixed it:

```
pkg install zlib-dev
```

after running this command run the following command again and both packages will be installed though it took a lot of time to complete:

```
$ LDFLAGS="-lm -lcompiler_rt" pip install numpy matplotlib
```

-cheers