# How do I view an ipynb file on android?

Tags: android, html, pdf, jupyter-notebook

1. I just want to view them not work on them so I don't mind an ipynb to PDF or HTML converter on android
2. I usually just convert them from my laptop or upload them to colab before printing them as PDF but those options aren't available to me right now, any app suggestions methods are welcome.

Comment: See this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49837474/how-do-i-install-jupyter-notebook-on-an-android-device

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Jupyter notebook on an Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49837474/how-do-i-install-jupyter-notebook-on-an-android-device)

Answer (score 0):

There are ipynb viewers available on playstore, although I have not tried them.

I generally just change the extension to txt from ipynb, but this will give you a bunch of currently useless information also.

Comment: More of a comment rather than an answer